# PHP: How do I print the key from array only once and every value for each item?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So here's my code:

```
foreach ($result->devices as $device) {
    $flag = false;
    foreach ($device as $key => $value) {
        if(!$flag){
            var_dump($key);
            $flag = true;
        }
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

What I try to achieve is to only print the key (description, brand, etc...) only once but print the value of all those keys for every device found. This is to make it eventually save as an .csv

Note: $result = a multidimensional array where I'm only interested in the devices section of it, hence the `$result->devices`.
The way this works now is it only prints the first key for every device found, what I get now looks something like:

```
string 'deviceId' (length=8) // keeps getting repeated
int 4268
string 'beschrijving nr 53' (length=18)
 ...
string 'deviceId' (length=8) // keeps getting repeated
int 4267
string 'Weer een tooltje' (length=16)
```

What I try to get is something resembling:

```
string 'deviceId' (length=8)
string 'description' (length=??)
string 'status' (length=??)
 ... // rest of keys, followed by devices
int 4268
string 'beschrijving nr 53' (length=18)
 ... // rest of values, followed by other devices
int 4267
string 'Weer een tooltje' (length=16)
```

I'm sure it's something simple like the wrong order of operation or moving something in/out a certain loop, but after having tried various variations, I'm none the wiser.

So to whom may solve this mystery, I thank you greatly.

Comment: add this `var_dump($value);` in else

Comment: It's not completely clear to what you want to achieve, and what you did yourself. Could you show us some of the code, and a proper example input array with example output csv. Then we might be able to help out properly

Comment: I would simplify it and separate writing the headers and data rows. Before the loop output the keys from the first array element. Then loop over all elements and output the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I suppose, your data looks kind of like this?

```
$result = (object)[];

$result->devices = [
    ['deviceId' => 1, 'description' => 'desc1', 'status' => 'status14'],
    ['deviceId' => 2, 'description' => 'desc2', 'status' => 'status15'],
    ['deviceId' => 3, 'description' => 'desc3', 'status' => 'status16'],
    ['deviceId' => 4, 'description' => 'desc2', 'status' => 'status17'],
];
```

Then to create a CSV file from it I would go like this:

```
$fp = fopen('csv.csv', 'w+');

foreach($result->devices as $i => $device)
{
    // First row? Write headers (keys) first!
    if($i == 0) fputcsv($fp, array_keys($device)); 

    // Write data rows
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($device));
}
fclose($fp);
```

This way, you will get this:

```
deviceID,description,status
1,desc1,status14
2,desc2,status15
3,desc3,status16
4,desc4,status17
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Interesting to use a normal array as a key => value pair.

Comment: @Oleg Dubas
I've tried that before, but the problem is, my object looks like this:
    $result->devices = [
        0 => [ (= object (stdClass))
            'deviceId' => 1,
            'description' => 'desc1', 
            ... 
        ],
        1 => [
            'deviceId' => 2, 
            ...
        ]
    ]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oleg Dubas, I've found the problem. It appears I was overcomplicating things (as I tend to do), in combination with trying to print out parts of an object, instead of having the object cast into an array. That's why when I tried a similar approach like this before, it didn't work. This is the new and working code:

```
foreach ($result->devices as $key => $device) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        fputcsv($out, array_keys((array)$device), "\t");
    }
    fputcsv($out, array_values((array)$device), "\t");
}
```

As you can see it is almost identical to Oleg's code, but I just had to cast the object to an associative array.

Thanks again for the help, Oleg. It was much appreciated.